# Правильное употребление предлога

Tags: предлог

Как правильно сказать: Эти логотипы узнаваемы по всей России или во всей России?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше "по всей России". Красивее.

Comment: В смысле? "красивше"?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос:  А что есть места, где не узнают?  Если узнают везде, тогда просто в России.